# Grafana query editor: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I've pulled the following grafana docker image and run it:

```
d1b62f18fb8d        grafana/grafana     "/run.sh"                27 hours ago        Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp           grafana
```

I set up a prometheus data source (using the prometheus docker container), and everything appears to be working, but when I go to start writing queries in Grafana for a new panel, there is a box "Loading..." and I don't get to see or edit the PromQL query there.  In developer tools, I see:

> VM199 editor.main.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

I can't find anything online about this.  How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you want to open a [github issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues) in the grafana repository about that.

Comment: Check network browser console, there can be some unexpected response from the server, so check also Grafana logs.

Comment: All 2xx responses.  I see http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range resulted in 200 as well and has a response body that looks reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not a great solution but I switched from Chrome to Safari and it started working.  Could be one of my Chrome extensions or something.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in newer browser versions and is fixed in the newer Grafana versions. If you are not able to update Grafana you can use the "Panel JSON" (Left Click on Panel > More > Panel JSON) functionality as a workaround to manually correct the query directly in the JSON.